# Wondering this error Type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:diary_sangiboo/utils.dart';

class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  late Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents;
  CalendarFormat format = CalendarFormat.month;
  DateTime selectedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime focusedDay = DateTime.now();

  TextEditingController _eventController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedEvents = {};
    super.initState();
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsfromDay(DateTime date) {
    return selectedEvents[date] ?? [];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _eventController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("한달 기록"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TableCalendar(
            focusedDay: selectedDay,
            firstDay: DateTime(1990),
            lastDay: DateTime(2050),
            calendarFormat: format,
            onFormatChanged: (CalendarFormat _format) {
              setState(() {
                format = _format;
              });
            },
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
            daysOfWeekVisible: true,

            //Day Changed
            onDaySelected: (DateTime selectDay, DateTime focusDay) {
              setState(() {
                selectedDay = selectDay;
                focusedDay = focusDay;
              });
              print(focusedDay);
            },
            selectedDayPredicate: (DateTime date) {
              return isSameDay(selectedDay, date);
            },

            eventLoader: _getEventsfromDay,

            //To style the Calendar
            calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
              isTodayHighlighted: true,
              selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ),
              selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ),
              defaultDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ),
              weekendDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ),
            ),
            headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
              formatButtonVisible: true,
              titleCentered: true,
              formatButtonShowsNext: false,
              formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ),
              formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ..._getEventsfromDay(selectedDay).map(
                (Event event) => ListTile(
              title: Text(
                event.title,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("출석체크를 하시겠습니까?"),
            content: TextFormField(
              controller: _eventController,
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: Text("Cancel"),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text("Ok"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) {

                  } else {
                    if (selectedEvents[selectedDay] != null) {
                      selectedEvents[selectedDay]?.add;
                    } else {
                      selectedEvents[selectedDay] = [
                      ];
                    }

                  }
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  _eventController.clear();
                  setState((){});
                  return;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        label: Text("Add button"),
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code. type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' error. Where should I fix this error and what code should I add?

I want to make it in the form of attendance check on the calendar. If today is May 28th, I would like to make a check mark or a color mark on May 28th to make an attendance mark. But there's an error. I don't know why. I'd like you to help me. Help me plz..

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not clear, I tested the code and you have an issues in `adding to events list` logic,

```
onPressed: () {
    if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) {

    } else {
        if (selectedEvents[selectedDay] != null) {
            selectedEvents[selectedDay]?.add;
        } else {
            selectedEvents[selectedDay] = [
            ];
        }

    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
    _eventController.clear();
    setState((){});
    return;
},
```

here, what do you mean by `selectedEvents[selectedDay]?.add;`?
also, in the else block, you are reinitializing the list, so the `List<Event>` will always be empty,

a proper code would be:

```
(selectedEvents[selectedDay] ??= []).add(Event(_eventController.text));
```

this code line will add an Event object to the list if its not null,
and if its null, it will create a new list and add the event to it,

**NOTE**: Your code did not add any Event object to the lists

Comment: (selectedEvents[selectedDay] ??= []).add(Event(_eventController.text)); Thank you for your answer. But Where should I put this code to get the execution screen? and 'The builder for route "null" returned null.' This new error pops up...

Comment: inside your **Ok** button.onPressed, the else code block remove it and put this line instead of it

Comment: TextButton(
                child: Text("Ok"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) {

                  }
                  (selectedEvents[selectedDay] ??= []).add(Event(_eventController.text));
                  }
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  _eventController.clear();
                  setState((){});
                  return;
Is that right??

Comment: Add a return statement inside the if statement block to avoid adding an empty event name to the list.  TextButton( child: Text("Ok"), onPressed: () { if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) { return; } (selectedEvents[selectedDay] ??= []).add(Event(_eventController.text)); } Navigator.pop(context); _eventController.clear(); setState((){});

Comment: Navigator.pop(context);  <- This code execution screen doesn't come up because of an error. What's wrong with copying and pasting?

Comment: What is the error? this code should close the dialog where you enter the event name

Comment: TextButton( child: Text("Ok"), onPressed: () { if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) { return; } (selectedEvents[selectedDay] ??= []).add(Event(_eventController.text)); } Navigator.pop(context); _eventController.clear(); setState((){}); return;},Is that right?? but Navigator.pop(context); is error... I'm sorry / positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments. Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. error